# Weblogic and correct nodemanager

Tags: java, weblogic

I do not have experience in weblogic, I know the basic.
I installed the weblogic 12.1.2.
I created: 1 domain, 2 machines, 2 managedservers, 1 admin server, 1 cluster.

I am following a book about the weblogic.
I need start the managed server 01, but when I start, the message is showed:

"For server PROD_Server01, the Node Manager associated with machine prod01 is not reachable."
"Message icon - Warning All of the servers selected are currently in a state which is incompatible with this operation or are not associated with a running Node Manager or you are not authorized to perform the action requested. No action will be performed.
"
I have two files "startNodemanager.sh"
A file in "/oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/bin"
Another file in "/oracle/Middleware/wlserver/server/bin"

When I execute the file em domain path, the service start ok, but I do not work start de managedserver

When I execute the file in wlsServer (2 example), I have the problem:
"ConfigException: Identity key store file not found: /oracle/Middleware/oracle_common/common/nodemanager/security/DemoIdentity.jks"

The question:
Which is the correct file for start?

Thanks,
Sorry, my english is bad :)

Comment: Have you enrolled the managed servers? Also, to get started, the easiest is to use the Plain Text mode via `SecureListener=false` inside the NM config and at the Console change the Nodemanager from SSL to Plain as well. I normally use the one under the `../wlserver/server/bin`.

Comment: Hi, I reinstall the weblogic and I did that you say, now it is ok.
thanks for help me.